# Random disconnection from Wi-Fi Network, usually after inactivity

Tags: iphone, wifi, jailbreak, network

My iPhone is jailbroken. Even though I'm not completely sure, I think it used to do this even before I installed the jailbreak.

Every time I pick up my iPhone after not using it for some time (sometimes just 10 minutes) and try to use some app that requires a connection or connect to a website on Safari, it will just hang there trying to load for a few seconds and then tell me it can't reach the server.

This is incredibly annoying because every time I want to connect I have to slide on the statusbar to open the Activator, click on the Wi-Fi button, wait till it's disabled and click again to enable it.
That's the only way to get it to reconnect.
Sometimes it will stop connecting even while it's being used, so if I'm downloading something that takes a long time to get through chances are high that it will stop downloading right in the middle.

I'd like to know a way to fix it not only because it's generally a pain in the ass, but also because I use the Remote app, and sometimes it randomly disconnects and I lose control over iTunes.

Now, I'm not completely sure about I think this might have never happened when I connected to other networks instead of my home one (which seems to be the only one to have this problem, but as I said I am not completely sure).

So yeah, does anybody know anything about this kind of issue? Might it be my iPhone's fault or my Wi-Fi router's? Also, I think this used to happen even before I updated to 4.3.3 (I had jailbreak version 4.1 before)

**EDIT**: I went into my router's settings and changed the wi-fi channel from 9 to 11. It doesn't seem to be disconnecting anymore. I'll wait some more and see if this is true.

**EDIT 2**: It didn't work. Same problem as before.

My router is a Cisco Linksys model no. WAG120N (Annex A)

Comment: Same thing happens to me on jailbroken iPhone 3G with latest firmware. Although I started noticing the problem immediately after changing my router and it persists on this particular router only.

Comment: My non-jailbroken phone drops all WiFi connections as soon as the screen dims. The app running has to make a call to prevent this sleep from happening. Have you modified your phone to not sleep the WiFi? Unless you have, the disconnection is on purpose and not at all random.

Comment: It disconnects even with the screen on.